# Unable to show entire web-page with only just background image

Tags: html, css

***What has been done:***

Have created the required Html tags as shown in the code below:

```
<html>

<head>
    ....
     ....
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>  
    <style style="text/css">
         html, body {
             padding: 0;
             margin: 0;
             position:relative;
             width: auto;
             height: auto;
        } 
        .container {
            width: 150px;
            align-content: center;
            margin-top: 980px;
            clear: both;
        }
        .container input {
            width: 82%;
            clear: both;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
     ...
      ...
    <div id="page4" align= "center" style=" background-image: url(Image/Page2.png); position: relative; z-index: 2; display:none" width="100%" height="100%" left="0px" top="0px">

        <form style=" alignment-adjust: autofocus; padding: 30px" class="container" action="Page5" method="POST">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="15px" required><br><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="15px" required><br><br>
        </form>
        <input type="image" src="image/Submit.png" alt="Submit" width="100px" height="50px" onClick = "Page5()">
    </div>

    <script>
        function Page5() {
            $("#page4").hide();
            $("#page5").show();
        }
    </script>


    <div id="page5" align= "center" style=" background-image: url(Image/Page5.png);position: relative; z-index: 3; display:none" width="100%" height="100%" >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Functionality:***

User is supposed to be able to view page 5 and the background image "Page 5" is being displayed, after the user has submitted the form in page 4. Hence, when user navigate from page 4 to page 5, user is suppose to the see the content of page 5 which is just the background image.

***Issue***

When user navigates from page 4 to 5, page 5's content is not displayed, the entire background image is not displaying. Hence, I would like to ask for help, 
1.) why is this happening
2.) what is the best rectification process

***NOTE***

I have to input the following attribute:

```
display:none
```

Reason: I have created the following stack in the form of block, hence the individual `<div>` block will only appear when the `<script>` is implemented. Hence, please do not suggest that I need to remove the `display:none` as doing so will 
 cause the  to merge and furthermore, it does nothing as well.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps remove "display:none" ?

Comment: @scrayne I have to put "display:none". Since i have put <z-index=n> attribute, I am putting each of them as a stack, hence that individual <div> will only appear upon the implementation of the <script>. If I were to remove "display:none", all the <div>tag will be merged, not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all there is no "width" and "height" attribute to div's so move the width and height declarations to CSS. Also add height 100% to html and body otherwise the div has no basis to calculate the height upon

```
html, body {
             padding: 0;
             margin: 0;
             position:relative;
             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
        } 
#page5{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arrhyppz/

P.S. use the inspect function of your browser to see the applied css, you will find where your mistakes are

Comment: It is weird, somehow, I am still unable to get the background out

Comment: you do see that in my jsfiddle you can see the background color right? than please provide the full code (and better yet use the inspect function)